# Z-6170 USB cable

Tags: usb, cables, pinout, barcode

I need to make a USB communication cable for the Zebex Z-6170 barcode reader. I found a reader pin-out description but I can't understand it. It is about powering the reader from USB and pin 1 (USB Power) and 2 (+ 5V).

My guess is that USB Power is Vbus and pin 2 (+5V) is possibility of connecting an external power supply, but I'm not sure.
Below is a link to the description of the barcode reader pin-out

[Z6170 Buyers Guide](https://www.zebex.com/uploads/files/Z-6170/Z-6170_BuyersGuide.pdf)

I suspect that the scheme should look like this:

Scanner - USB 
Pin 1 - Pin 1 (power) 
Pin 3 - Pin 2 (Data -) 
Pin 8 - Pin 3 (Data +) 
Pin 5 - Pin 4 (GND / VSS)

but I'm not sure.

Comment: power is pin 2, the rest of the wiring scheme looks correct ... don't forget that the scanner has a 10 pin jack, so if you use an RJ45 connector, then you are connecting to pins 2 through 9

Answer (score 1):

This is the table in the [buyers guide](https://www.zebex.com/uploads/files/Z-6170/Z-6170_BuyersGuide.pdf):

[image: Z-6170 buyers guide: table]

It specifies 10P10C connector. For an 8P8C connector the mapping would be

- RJ45 pin 1 - +5V
- RJ45 pin 2 - D-
- RJ45 pin 4 - GND
- RJ45 pin 7 - D+

An RJ45 connector can be inserted into such an RJ50 socket, the pin counting is then reduced by one.

> This connector is also used by some vendors, [...] allowing an 8P8C plug to be inserted to their 10P10C socket for most applications.

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_connector#10P10C)

Comment: you gave the mapping for RJ50 (10pin).

Comment: You're right. Fixed the numbering and added another reference!

Answer (score 1):

I send information directly from technical support zebex. 
Note the additional barcode scanner pinout connection:

Scanner (RJ50) - USB 
1-2 (USB Power, + 5V) - 1 
6-7 (TxD - RxD)

[image]